# Azure Functions - NodeJS - Response Body as a Stream

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I'd like to return a file from Blob Storage when you hit a given Azure Function end-point. This file is binary data.

Per the Azure Storage Blob docs, the most relevant call appears to be the following since its the only one that doesn't require writing the file to an interim file:

`getBlobToStream`

However this call gets the Blob and writes it to a stream.

Is there a way with Azure Functions to use a Stream as the value of res.body so that I can get the Blob Contents from storage and immediately write it to the response?

To add some code, trying to get something like this to work:

```
'use strict';
const   azure = require('azure-storage'),
        stream = require('stream');
const BLOB_CONTAINER = 'DeContainer';

module.exports = function(context){
    var file = context.bindingData.file;
    var blobService = azure.createBlobService();
    var outputStream = new stream.Writable();

    blobService.getBlobToStream(BLOB_CONTAINER, file, outputStream, function(error, serverBlob) {
        if(error) {
            FileNotFound(context);
        } else {
            context.res = {
                status: 200,
                headers: {

                },
                isRaw: true,
                body : outputStream
            };
            context.done();


        }
    });
}

function FileNotFound(context){
    context.res =  {
        status: 404,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        },
        body : { "Message" : "No esta aqui!."}
    };
    context.done();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately we don't have streaming support implemented in NodeJS just yet - it's on the backlog: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1361

If you're not tied to NodeJ open to using a C# function instead, you can use the storage sdk object directly in your input bindings and stream request output, instead of using the intermediate object approach.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the answer, but thank-you for answering it just the same! I'll see how I might be able to work around this.

Answer (score 8):

While @Matt Manson's answer is definitely correct based on the way I asked my question, the following code snippet might be more useful for someone who stumbles across this question.

While I can't send the Stream to the response body directly, I can use a custom stream which captures the data into a Uint8Array, and then sends that to the response body.

NOTE: If the file is REALLY big, this will use a lot of memory.

```
'use strict';
const   azure = require('azure-storage'),
        stream = require('stream');
const BLOB_CONTAINER = 'deContainer';

module.exports = function(context){
    var file = context.bindingData.file;
    var blobService = azure.createBlobService();
    var outputStream = new stream.Writable();
    outputStream.contents = new Uint8Array(0);//Initialize contents.

    //Override the write to store the value to our "contents"
    outputStream._write = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
        var curChunk = new Uint8Array(chunk);
        var tmp = new Uint8Array(this.contents.byteLength + curChunk.byteLength);
        tmp.set(this.contents, 0);
        tmp.set(curChunk, this.contents.byteLength);
        this.contents = tmp;
        done();
    };


    blobService.getBlobToStream(BLOB_CONTAINER, file, outputStream, function(error, serverBlob) {
        if(error) {
            FileNotFound(context);
        } else {
            context.res = {
                status: 200,
                headers: {

                },
                isRaw: true,
                body : outputStream.contents
            };
            context.done();
        }
    });//*/
}

function FileNotFound(context){
    context.res =  {
        status: 404,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        },
        body : { "Message" : "No esta aqui!"}
    };
    context.done();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried @Doug's solution from the last comment above, with a few minor mods in my azure function, and so far, after trying 20 different ideas, this is the only one that actually delivered the file to the browser!  Thank you, @Doug...

```
const fs = require("fs");
const stream = require("stream");

...

                const AzureBlob = require('@[my_private_artifact]/azure-blob-storage');
                const azureStorage = new AzureBlob(params.connectionString);


                //Override the write to store the value to our "contents" <-- Doug's solution
                var outputStream = new stream.Writable();
                outputStream.contents = new Uint8Array(0);//Initialize contents.

                outputStream._write = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
                    var curChunk = new Uint8Array(chunk);
                    var tmp = new Uint8Array(this.contents.byteLength + curChunk.byteLength);
                    tmp.set(this.contents, 0);
                    tmp.set(curChunk, this.contents.byteLength);
                    this.contents = tmp;
                    done();
                };

                let azureSpeedResult = await azureStorage.downloadBlobToStream(params.containerName, params.objectId, outputStream);

                let headers = {
                    "Content-Length": azureSpeedResult.size,
                    "Content-Type": mimeType
                };

                if (params.action == "download") {
                    headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=" + params.fileName;
                } 

                context.res = {
                    status: 200,
                    headers: headers,
                    isRaw: true,
                    body: outputStream.contents
                };

                context.done();
...
```