# Azure functions compressed POST body

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I have nodejs azure function with the Http trigger. I am using POST method and sending body to the azure function. Since body is large it is compressed using gzip.

I am getting the request in azure function and the content-encoding header is 'gzip'. I tried to use nodejs

```
zlib.gunzip(req.body,...)
```

and it threw an error

> Error: incorrect header check

Answer (score 7):

For JavaScript functions, [streaming is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810082/azure-functions-nodejs-response-body-as-a-stream/43811778#43811778) and the Functions runtime provides the request body instead of the request object. There is no special handling for C# functions, so you could try using a C# function instead.

Here is a C# function which decompresses gzip request body for your reference.

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO.Compression;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    var inputStream = await req.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    string decompressedReqBody = string.Empty;
    using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(decompressionStream))
        {
           decompressedReqBody = sr.ReadToEnd();
           log.Info(decompressedReqBody);
        }
    }
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, decompressedReqBody);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Faced similar issue recently. Mistake we did was to set wrong `Content-Type` header. Changing `Content-Type` to `application/octet-stream` from `application/json` did the trick.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)